# How to populate database information from dropdown selection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a students table, a courses table and a student/courses table to show the students enrolled in a course. The table is in SQL Server 2008 and the front end in C# and Asp.net.

In the student/courses table I would like to be able to have a dropdown menu that will allow me to select the student ID stored on the database and then populate the student's name, last name and middle initial in a textbox or label.

How can I possibly do this? Any examples? Thank you for your help!

Comment: users table is same as the student table??

Comment: Start with [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx.aspx).

Comment: @PraveenNambiar my bad, it is supposed to be the same. I made the change. Thanks!

Comment: @Brian I'm not very familiar with ADO.NET. How does it work?

Comment: @ElianaLopezSanchez - That is a very large question you have asked... Basically, it is a means for you to be able to 'talk' to and manipulate a database via code (like C#, VB and the like).  In my comment above, ADO.NET is hyperlinked to take you to the documentation/getting started page for it.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/presenting-and-managing-data

Answer (score 1):

You can use either ADO.net, if not familiar then

on page load event

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection= new Class1().getconnection();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Profile";
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(dr["YahooId"].ToString());
    }
```

in "cmd.CommandText" instead of "Profile" use your table name, and under "while(dr.read()) use your column name instead of "YahooId"